# Add mulitple vertical dots between two buttons that they are one bellow another

Tags: html, css

Im trying to add dots between buttons, something like this:
[image]

this is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0xpy61n5/

```css
    .asset-detail {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding:10px;
        line-height:30px;
        border: 1px solid var(--highlight-color-5);
        background:var(--highlight-color-7);
        border-radius:5px;
        position:relative;
    }
  span {
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }

    .asset {
        display: flex;
    }

    .asset-tabs{
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
    .toggle{
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        float: left;
    }
    .wrapper{
        float: right;
        margin-left: 30px;
        width: 90%;
    }
.textarea{
    resize: none;
    width:90%;
}
ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    li{
        list-style-type: none;
        margin-left: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    &:hover{
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
}


button{
  margin-bottom:120px
}
```

```html
            <div>
      <button>
      +
      </button>
                            <span class="toggle" ><i class="fa-light"></i></span>
                            <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="row mt-20">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="col-24">Created:<span>aaa</span></div>
                                    <div class="col-24">Created by:<span>bbbb</span></div>
            
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="col-24"><textarea class="textarea" rows="6" disabled>cccc</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          
                    <div>
      <button>
      +
      </button>
                            <span class="toggle" ><i class="fa-light"></i></span>
                            <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="row mt-20">
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="col-24">Created:<span>aaa</span></div>
                                    <div class="col-24">Created by:<span>bbbb</span></div>
            
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-6">
                                    <div class="col-24"><textarea class="textarea" rows="6" disabled>cccc</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Any suggestion how to achive this or where i can see that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an `border-left` with `dotted` or `dashed` to achieve it.

```css
div {
  height:96px;
  width: 48px;
  border-left: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: ➕1 but `{ height: 40px; width: 4px; border-left: 4px dotted black; }`